# Coporate Exchange Mobile client access Policies .. why so many still require RIM

Tags: email, exchange, android, webmail

My employer use to only allow mobile access to exchange to RIM (Blackberry) devices or so at least that is what they said. At some point when I asked, they acknowledged that iOS and Android devices were also accessing exchange and so today I'm using an Android device for both work and personal email.

My wife's employer has a strick access polcies (at least written policies) and requires her to carry a RIM device which they install a PW policy on.  She can use that phone for limited personal use if she wants, but they would have her call logs and some traffic wil be logged as well so like many she toggles  2 phones, but uses only her peronal for calls and text messages. What are the chances this employer has webmail access and what are the chances if she has the mail server address that she will just able to just be able to access corporate mail from her Android phone?

More of an HR question, but would attempting to configure access and gaining access to exchange by just figuring it out (which i think is the only real security barrier here)  be considered hacking into their system?  The person who handles the phones there has a title of phone specialist but  is not an exchange admin or technical at all, I suspect they were just reading from the handbook when she first asked about using her personal phone to access corporate mail.

Is there any legit reason why so many employers still require RIM? Any real reason employers need to install a polciy (or anything else) on mobile devices accessing corporate exchange?

Beyond asking for the webmail url and exchange server address, what's the best way to discover these?

Comment: RIM *still* has the only email that offers strong end-to-end encryption, which is important to some employers. RIM also allows much better control of the remote device than iOS/Android/WinPhone, it's easier to enforce good behavior on the platform than the consumer-focused phone-OS.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Question is basically on why RIM over other platforms.  They currently allow iPhone and iPad access to exchange, is that any more secure than Android?  any way to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

She'll have to talk to her IT.  They can either help or offer clues for unsupported scenarios. Anything else is probably (or should be) breach of corporate policy and terms for sanction.